# How to remove all tab items except one in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to remove all tab items when i click the logout button
My code is given below

```
foreach (object item  in mainTab.Items)
{
  TabItem ti = (TabItem)item;
  if ("welcomeTabItem" != ti.Name)
    {
      mainTab.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

But this will create a following error

> *error-Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

Is any other method is existing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get the desired item, then clear the control and add the item back.

```
// Note that `First` will throw an exception if the item isn't found.
TabItem ti = mainTab.Items.First(t => t.Name == "WelcomTabItem");
mainTab.Items.Clear();
mainTab.Items.Add(ti);
```

Alternatively, if "WelcomeTabItem" may not be in `Items`:

```
TabItem ti = mainTab.Items.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "WelcomTabItem");
mainTab.Items.Clear();
if(ti != null)
    mainTab.Items.Add(ti);
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot edit `IEnumerables` in `foreach` loops. insted use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = mainTab.Items.Count -1; i >=0; i--)
{
  TabItem ti = (TabItem)mainTab.Items[i];
  if ("welcomeTabItem" != ti.Name)
   {
     mainTab.Items.Remove(ti);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just note that it is very important that you decrement `i`, since remove item indexes to shift, which would cause you to skip items if you start at `0` and increment `i`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LINQ` to remove items like this -

```
mainTab.Items.RemoveAll(ti => ((TabItem)ti).Name != "welcomeTabItem");
```

Make sure to add `using System.Linq;` namespace at top of your file.

Answer (score 3):

Editing an Enumerable inside a Foreach is not allowed

You could use the below LINQ code, to remove all the items except "welcomeTabItem":

```
mainTab.Items.RemoveAll(i => i.Name != "welcomeTabItem");
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what the asker wants to do.

Comment: @jacobaloysious: Your solution is nice, but as Jason said manuthalasseril is going to remove all but one of the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
var itemsToRemove = new List(TabItem);

foreach (object item  in mainTab.Items)
{
  TabItem ti = (TabItem)item;
  if ("welcomeTabItem" != ti.Name)
   {
     itemsToRemove.Add(item);
   }
}

foreach (var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
{
    mainTab.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

You cannot remove items from a collection while you enumerating it